# Quarkus+Apache Camel+Swagger ui

Tags: spring-boot, apache-camel, maven-2, quarkus

I'm currently working on Quarkus with swagger ui and followed a link to test it below link successfully https://quarkus.io/guides/openapi-swaggerui.

but is there any way to implement apache camel route with swagger ui in quarkus? kindly help me.

Answer (score 0):

If you add the `camel-quarkus-openapi-java` extension to your application, then you can add documentation to your REST DSL routes and have it rendered as an OpenAPI document. There's more information on how to do this here:

https://camel.apache.org/manual/latest/rest-dsl.html

Then you can configure the default URL that the Swagger UI points to.

For example, assuming you configured your Camel OpenAPI documentation to be served at `/openapi.yaml`, you can configure the Quarkus Swagger UI extension to consume it.

```
camel.rest.api-context-path = /openapi.yaml
quarkus.swagger-ui.urls.camel = /openapi.yaml
```

Comment: Dear James, I would like to thank for your instant support, my issue has been resolved and successfully configure swagger ui with camel + quarkus after changing properties file

Comment: my properties file configuration are below quarkus.camel.servlet.url-patterns=/api/*
camel.rest.api-context-path=/api/api-doc
quarkus.swagger-ui.urls.camel=/api/api-doc